# get url from python

Tags: python, curl

good day!
I need to send a request via the api to the https server. the documentation describes that this must be done via curl.
example request:

[image]

everything works out through curl. the request is sent, the response comes ok.

but if I try to send the same request with a python script, I get a 401 error.

here is my code.

```
import requests


def main():
    token = 'my_token'
    # url = 'https://api-ip.fssp.gov.ru/api/v1.0/'
    url = 'https://api-ip.fssp.gov.ru/api/v1.0/search/physical'
    region = '48'
    lastname = 'Иванов'
    firstname = 'Валерий'
    secondname = 'Викторович'
    birthdate = '02.07.1970'

    data = {
    'token': token,
    'region': region,
    'lastname': lastname,
    'firstname': firstname,
    'birthdate': birthdate,
    'secondname': secondname
    }

    response = requests.get(url=url, data=data)

    print(response.status_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

here is the content of the response from the server

```
b'{"status":"error","code":401,"exception":"token not exist","response":[]}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wanted to start working on this by verifying that everything works via curl. But then you made things difficult by only including a screenshot.

Comment: [Don't upload images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You're also passing more parameters than in the curl command you say works - and the 401 code suggests that you may have made a mistake in copying / encoding / .. the token, because it means 'unauthorised'. It's also possible that the site simply doesn't like that you're coming in using Python and you may need to pretend being another User-agent. I don't feel like trying my luck on https://api-ip.fssp.gov.ru/api/v1.0/search/physical

Comment: That's still an image, by the way - if you'd take the time to see why people don't like images, not being able to copy paste ranks pretty high.

Comment: You're not passing the required API key

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`params` argument](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) instead of `data` to URL encode the values:

```
    response = requests.get(url=url, params=data)
```